# call by reference in verilog code

Tags: verilog

I am trying to change a c++ code into verilog HDL.
I want to write a module that changes one of its inputs. (some how like call by reference in c++)
as I know there is no way to write a call by reference module in verilog (I can't use systemverilog)
Here is a code that I wrote and it works. are there any better ways to do this?!
my problme is that the register I want to be call by reference is a big array. this way duplicates the registers and has a lot of cost.

```
module testbench();
reg a;
wire b;
reg clk;
initial begin
    a = 0;
    clk = 0;
    #10
    clk = 1;
end

test test_instance(
    .a(a),
    .clk(clk),
    .aOut(b)
    );

always@(*)begin
        a = b;
end
endmodule



module test(
    input a,
    input clk,
    output reg aOut
    );
    always @(posedge clk) begin
        if (a == 0)begin
            a = 1;
            aOut = a;
        end
    end

endmodule
```

Comment: You need to provide a lot more information about your "requirements". I presume you are trying to translate a software algorithm into hardware. A direct translation of the procedural flow will most likely not work. Also, why are you not able to use SystemVerilog?

Comment: Yes I'm trying to translate a software algorithm into hdl. the algorithm is so complicated that i can't change it to hardware. so I shoul change it line by line to hdl code

Comment: Given your answer to be below ("logic area"), it sounds like changing your algorithm to hardware is _exactly_ what you are trying to. And when you write HDL code for implementation on an FPGA or IC, designing hardware is _exactly_ what you are doing. You need to start converting your algorithm to hardware and then to code that in your HDL. An HDL is not a way of avoiding designing hardware. There are tools available that will convert C code to HDL code/hardware, but they are not a quick fix - you need quite a lot of practice using them before you get the results you are after.

Comment: @MatthewTaylor Tnx, yes You Are right. but this is a competition and I have a little time for it.(we have a C file and we should design hardware and give the layout to them. and the algorithm is h264 motion estimator) so there is no time to learn the algorithm and then design hardware for it. I translate it exactly from c to verilog and it works. but I didn't use any module.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it really about hardware design, not programming. It belongs in Electrical Engineering

Answer (score 1):

Verilog is not a *software* programming language; it is a *hardware* description language. The inputs to a module are pieces of metal (wires, tracks, pins); the outputs from a module are pieces of metal. If you want a port that is both an input and an output you can use an `inout`. However, `inout` ports are best avoided; it is usually much better to use separate inputs and outputs.

A Verilog *module* is not a software function. Nothing is copied to the inputs; nothing is copied from the outputs. A Verilog module is a lump of hardware: it has inputs (pieces of metal carrying information in) and outputs (pieces of metal carrying information out).

Your are right to say that you can use either pass-by-copy or pass-by-reference in SystemVerilog. If you wish to pass a large data structure into a function or into/out of a task, then passing by reference may save simulation time.

Comment: thanx, I know. You are right. as you can see I got two different input and input of the module to do that. but I want to know is there any better way to do that with a little cost

Comment: Actually, SystemVerilog does have pass by reference for module ports. But that won't help this person.

Comment: Thank you@dave_59. Actually, some feint bell is ringing. I had better revise that.

Comment: @Mehdi What do you mean by cost? Simulation time? Logic area?

Comment: @MatthewTaylor I mean logic area

Answer (score 0):

By reference means by address, so to translate this to hdl directly you would either need to provide a way for the module to get on that bus and perform transactions based on that address.

Or better, if you need this as an input take each of the items in the struct and make individual inputs from them.  If it is pass by reference because it is an output or is also an output, then you create individual outputs for each of the items in the struct.  The module then distinguishes between the input version of that sub item and output version of that sub item.

my.thing.x = my.thing.x + 1;

becomes something like

my_thing_x_output = my_thing_x_input + 1;

Comment: are you sure this works ?! can you recreate my sample?!

Comment: how do you think hardware or software modules/functions work?  inputs and outputs, and the module/function modifies the input to make an output.  why wouldnt that work?